# Need some Help verifying if my statistics problems b,c,d are correct

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

So for b I multiplied .19 and .06 and got .0114
for c I added .0114 and (.81*.48) and got .4002
for d I multiplied .81*.48 and got .3888

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with your number of decimal places.

For example, for (b) the answer should be 0.011 to 3d.p. not 0.0114.

Comment: for b, c and d, the number of decimal place doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Your method for (b) and (c) look correct. BUT they have asked you to enter your answers to 3 decimal places, so you have been marked wrong.

Your method for (d) is incorrect. They've given you a hint to calculate the conditional probability... good idea.

Comment: I just submitted the hw and c was correct.